# Chaining gnuplot function calls in TikZ, reverse plotting

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

[image: parabolic bridge arch]

I have a parabola drawn through A, B and C. There are three different equations: for the top darker border, the fill (this is a hack just using a wide line) and the lower border. It's not quite what I want.

I'd like to emphasize that there are two separate sections of the arch which are pinned together at B so I am trying to draw AB on its own. In red, I plot the function for the upper border from A to almost B, then use an arc to touch at B and reach to bottom border of the arch.

I would like to chain a function call to my statement (the last statement below) that will plot the formula of the lower border of the arch from B back to A.

I'm not sure of the syntax:

1. How do a I chain a function call, with a different domain from the first call in the statement?
2. When plotting the parabola of the bottom border of the arch from B back to A, I need to draw the parabola from right to left (`B_x` to `A_x`). Is this possible?

```latex
 % arch fill (central formula)
 \draw[domain=4.2:13.825, color=LightCyan3, line width=0.375cm, line cap=rect] plot[id=1] function{-3*x*x/32+3*x/2};

 % upper arch border
 \draw[domain=3.85:14.187, color=LightCyan4, thick] plot[id=2] function{-.090215*x*x+1.4425*x+0.48342};

 % lower arch border
 \draw[domain=4.15:13.813, color=LightCyan4, thick] plot[id=3] function{-0.097567*x*x+1.5621*x-0.50220};

 % incomplete red border
 \draw[domain=3.85:7.75, draw=red, fill=none, very thick]plot[id=4] function{-0.090211*x*x+1.4425*x+0.48342}arc(90:-90:0.25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely I do not fully understand or appreciate what you want. Yes, you can reverse the plot, and I do not think you need gnuplot for such a simple function.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes,fit,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[domain=4.2:13.825, color=cyan, line width=0.375cm, line cap=rect] plot[id=1] function{-3*x*x/32+3*x/2};

 % upper arc border
 \draw[domain=3.85:14.187, color=cyan, thick] plot[variable=\x] 
 ({\x},{-.090215*\x*\x+1.4425*\x+0.48342});

 % lower arc border
 \draw[domain=4.15:13.813, color=cyan, thick] plot[variable=\x] 
 ({\x},{-0.097567*\x*\x+1.5621*\x-0.50220});

 % incomplete red border
 \draw[draw=red, fill=none, very thick,fill=red!20]
 plot[domain=3.85:7.75,variable=\x] ({\x},{-0.090211*\x*\x+1.4425*\x+0.48342})
 arc(90:-90:0.25)
 plot[domain=7.75:3.85,variable=\x] ({\x},{-0.097567*\x*\x+1.5621*\x-0.50220})
 -- (3.85,{-0.090211*3.85*3.85+1.4425*3.85+0.48342}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For fun, I also shaded the contour. If you don't like this, just remove the `fill=red!20` statement and `-- (3.85,{-0.090211*3.85*3.85+1.4425*3.85+0.48342})` (but not the semicolon).

Comment: You understood perfectly. :)